# How to call data frames from Global environment using list of names in values

Tags: r

I have set of data fames in Global environment importing by using

```
setwd("D:/dir/")

filenames <- list.files(pattern=".*csv")

for(i in filenames){
  filepath <- file.path(paste(i,sep=","))

  assign(i, read.csv(filepath, sep = ",", header=TRUE))

}
```

now i want to assign names in filenames(which are abc.csv,qwe.csv,xyz.csv) as dataframes in for loop as shown below

```
funct = function(x)
{
  for (i in substr(unique(x),1,3))

    i  <# create df name by assign 1st dataframe name from filenames# >  =  i <from global environment>
    male<-i[which(i$Level == "male"),]
    male$tot_sal = male$sal+male$bonus
    assign('male',male,envir=parent.frame()) #repeat loop for all 3 filename
}

funct(filenames)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should use a list for this, and not manually assign variables.  Lists can be indexed by name, making them suitable for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand your code and the idea behind it.

I used a list approach and a tidyverse/dplyr solution

```
library(tidyverse)
setwd("D:/dir/")    
filenames <- list.files(pattern=".*csv")

# read your files but store them in a list, where the key is the filename
my_files <- list()
for(i in filenames){
  filepath <- file.path(paste(i,sep=","))
  my_files[[i]]<- read.csv(filepath, sep = ",", header=TRUE)
}

# iterate over each file/df, filter for male and calculate the total
my_male_tot_list <- lapply(my_files, function(x){    
  x %>% 
    filter(Level == 'male') %>% # first filter for only males (i guess that is what you want to do)
    mutate(tot_sal = sal+bonus) # create a new column with the tot_sal
})
```

Since I am not sure if this is exactly what you want to retrieve, please feel free to comment if you want something a little bit different.